# Did Luke Skywalker rebuild the Jedi Order?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Which planet, and how many Jedi did Luke Skywalker train when he rebuilt the Jedi Order?

Comment: Your title and you body ask different questions. What are you actually asking?

Comment: unless “did” is synonymous with “on which planet and how many”, then no, I wouldn’t.

Answer (score 10):

### Canon

He tried, but it ended poorly so he gave up.

> Luke's student, Han and Leia's son Ben, turned to the Dark Side and became Kylo Ren.

As a result, Luke went into seclusion and stopped training Jedi. There seems to be some expectation that he will rebuild the Order in the future, but we'll have to wait for more films to see how that turns out.

### Legends

In the old Expanded Universe, which is now the non-canon Legends continuity, Luke's Jedi Order established its home on [Yavin IV](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yavin_4), with an initial pool of 12 recruits<sup>1</sup>. From the linked Wookieepedia page:

> In 11 ABY, Jedi Master Luke Skywalker chose Yavin 4 as the site for the Jedi Praxeum and the headquarters of his New Jedi Order after receiving permission from the New Republic. During his travels, he had discovered a number of Force-sensitives and finally felt ready to begin to train new Jedi. This first class consisted of twelve pupils with Luke as their teacher. Some of those twelve were Kam and Tionne Solusar, Kirana Ti, Madurrin, Kyle Katarn, Dorsk 81, Brakiss, Corran Horn, Streen, and Gantoris. Other Jedi to join soon after were Kyp Durron, Cilghal, Mara Jade, and Dal Konur.

Of course the order quickly grows beyond this, both as Luke and his Praxeum discover new Force-sensitives and as pre-Empire Jedi reveal that they were just hiding the whole time.

One example of the former, which [ShemSeger](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81917/did-luke-skywalker-rebuild-the-jedi-order#comment175460_81919) points me to in comments and which is, based on your [other question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81920/did-luke-skywalker-go-to-the-dark-side), possibly the incident you're referring to, occurs in issue 3 of [*Dark Empire II*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Empire_II_3:_World_of_the_Ancient_Sith): "World of the Ancient Sith".

In this issue Luke and Kam Solusar travel to the planet Ossus, which housed a Jedi Academy millenia before the Clone Wars and was wiped out by then-Dark Lord of the Sith [Exar Kun](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Exar_Kun). On the planet they discover the descendants of the survivors, the Force-sensitive [Ysanna](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ysanna). From what I can tell, only two of the Ysanna were ever trained as Jedi.

The numbers of the latter are legion, and Wookieepedia has a [tremendous list of survivors of the Great Jedi Purge](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Great_Jedi_Purge#Known_survivors_or_unaccounted_Jedi_as_of_the_end_of_the_Purge.3B_1_BBY). Not all of them joined Luke's academy, but a good many of them did.

---

<sup>1</sup> [I'm just going to leave this here...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostle_(Christian)#The_twelve_apostles)

Comment: This question is coming from something I remember reading in the Dark Horse Comics series

Comment: @mossberg Can you be more specific?

Comment: There was an audio drama about Luke finding the planet of force-sensitives. If I remember correctly it was protected by an old Jedi that had transformed himself into a tree... Also, Luke falls in love with one of the tribal girls.

Comment: @ShemSeger That sounds like [an issue of *Dark Empire II*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Empire_II_3:_World_of_the_Ancient_Sith), but I didn't know it got turned into an audio play. The more you know

Comment: Do you have confirmation on your 1st student claim? I got that they were *a* student, but didn't catch they were the *1st*, especially since there were others.

Comment: @CreationEdge I just got back from the theatre, and I'm pretty sure it was said at some point; entirely possible I'm misremembering, though, so I'll pull it out for now

Comment: @JasonBaker If I see it again before you do, I'll keep it in mind to verify!

Answer (score 2):

As of 2023, we have more details on Luke's [new Jedi Order](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Order) in Canon, including the planet he built his temple on and the minimum number of students he had.

[Luke's temple](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Temple_of_Luke_Skywalker) is first seen on [Ossus](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ossus) in an early stage of construction circa 9 ABY. Luke is shown to have a friendship with Ahsoka and tries to train Grogu, but it's unclear whether he has any other students at this point.

[image: Screenshot showing Ahsoka, R2-D2, and The Mandalorian looking at crab-like droids building a stone temple in a clearing on a forested world]

<sub>[*The Book of Boba Fett*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_6:_From_the_Desert_Comes_a_Stranger) ([via Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/File:ConstructionofSkywalkerSchool-BoBFCh6.png))</sub>

Eventually, Luke finished the temple and trained at least seven students, including Ben Solo.

[image: Comic panel showing Luke Skywalker and R2-D2 with Ben Solo and six other Jedi trainees levitating rocks outside a temple]

<sub>[*The Rise of Kylo Ren*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Kylo_Ren) ([via Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/File:Luke_teaching_Jedi.jpg))</sub>

In 28 ABY, six years before *The Force Awakens*, Ben Solo destroyed the temple, leading Luke to go into exile. Ben left to seek out the Knights of Ren, pursued by the remaining Jedi trainees, who were eventually killed.

[image: A cloaked Luke Skywalker and R2-D2 watching the Jedi temple burn]

<sub>[*The Last Jedi*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_VIII_The_Last_Jedi) ([via Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/File:LukesTempleBurning-TLJ.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I'm not a big deal Hollywood guy so it wouldn't occur to me to have the first movie set after Return of the Jedi be how they didn't return.

Comment: @lucasbachmann It was the singular Jedi, not the plural Jedi.